# Feature request for customized front page of Stack Exchange iOS App

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-feed

After using v0.1.11, I would like to request allowing customization of the front page of the app - that is, pick a feed to display. A feed can be:

- a favorite search query
- a favorite tag
- a specific stack site

Comment: I'd suggest doing #3 as well.  Its fate may be uncertain, but at least that way we can keep related comments and eventual outcome together.

Answer (score 2):

These suggestions have a pretty high variance in required effort to implement, and they aren't really related to one another.  I can tell you that #3 will most likely be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), but 1, 2, & 4 would best be handled as separate requests.

**Update**: there is an implementation of 1 & 2 that covers most use cases: saved searches:

- [Show recent searches in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229483/show-recent-searches-in-ios-app/243537#243537)
- ["Favorite" Views/Searches in iOS/Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/favorite-views-searches-in-ios-android-app/243538#243538)

Comment: Damnit, I wanted 3 the most. :)

Comment: Sorry :-).  We'll discuss it internally, but I wouldn't want anyone to get false hope.

Comment: I know that for me, I am less interested to see all that is happening. I want to instantly see what is happening in 1 specific tag or query. That's how I do it in the website... and even more so on the go. Less tapping, searching...

Comment: I want to second @IdanAdar here; if I can't restrict the main feed to a single or small list of tags, the whole app is basically useless to me.

Comment: @joran one of the reasons that doesn't really make sense in the feed is that tags don't have meaning across the network.  We will let you browse questions on a site-tag basis on the questions view, and if you leave the app on that view that's where it will start, which should accomplish most of what you're after (if you're only interested in one site)

Comment: @BenCollins That makes sense, I guess. It's just that the only way I appear to be able to browse SO questions by a single tag is to search for that tag, which then pins the search box at the top. Seems like kind of an inefficient use of space, for something that I would think would be pretty common.

Comment: I edited the question since 1, 2, 4 stand alone. Should this entire answer and comment thread be a comment now on the main question?

Comment: @bmike Nah, I think it's fine like it is.  Further discussion really belongs on the new posts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @bmike.

Comment: Has this been revisited internally? If there is one thing that makes me not-use the app as opposed to the mobile website is the fact that I cannot set it to look at ONLY my preference of tags or query.

Comment: @IdanAdar yes.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229483/show-recent-searches-in-ios-app/243537#243537 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/favorite-views-searches-in-ios-android-app/243538#243538

Comment: Ohhhh, very cool. If you'll update the answer I'll mark it as Answered. :)

Comment: Btw, I couldn't spot quick access to that favorite search. Planned?

Comment: My sources tell me this is now in the released version of the app, so you might just need an update.