# Show recent searches in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, ios-app

A lot has been said about searching and filtering in the iOS app. This proposal is by far the easiest to implement, but provides a majority of the functionality desired:

> [image: search history]

When you're typing in the search field, use the area between the search bar and the keyboard to show recent searches, possibly filtered by the text in the search bar.

Thus every search is saved and easy to restore. Searches would also be saved per site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the beta channel.

[image: recent and saved searches]

Comment: This is phenomenally better than I could have even anticipated.

Comment: What's the latest on this? Current app only shows last three searches, which is a bit limited.

Comment: Will this ever be brought to the Android app?

Comment: @zondo very very slim chance it will ever be done, nobody is working on the android app for long months by now. They don't fix bugs, so adding "nice to have" features is just a wild fantasy.