# Favorite Tags Feed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ios-app, tag-watching

I used the [SOStacked iOS app](http://sostacked.jldagon.me/) for a long time before the official Stack Exchange app came out. One thing that I loved about the SOStacked iOS app was that it provided the same functionality as [the bookmark I use on my desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js+or+browserify+or+gulp+or+requirejs+or+slickgrid+or+soundmanager2+or+web-audio+or+underscore.js+or+lodash.js+or+backbone.js+or+html5-audio+or+xmlhttprequest+or+promise+or+cross-domain+or+soundcloud+or+amqp+or+rabbitmq?sort=active&pagesize=50): I am able to get a feed of all my favorite tags sorted by activity ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHmQW.png)).

I don't seem to be able to replicate the same functionality on the Stack Exchange iOS app. I see there's a "Tags" view which shows me a list of my favorite tags, but I can only view questions from one tag at a time instead of a feed of all those questions together ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwQo.png)).

I was sort of able to recreate the desired functionality by going to the "Questions" view and entering a similar search ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clXX9.png)). However as you can see from the screenshot there are duplicate rows in the list where one row is for the actual question and another is for an answer to said question. There doesn't appear to be any way to filter out answers when searching so this is also not satisfactory.

I would like to request a feature for the Stack Exchange iOS app that will duplicate the functionality provided by [the bookmark I use on my desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js+or+browserify+or+gulp+or+requirejs+or+slickgrid+or+soundmanager2+or+web-audio+or+underscore.js+or+lodash.js+or+backbone.js+or+html5-audio+or+xmlhttprequest+or+promise+or+cross-domain+or+soundcloud+or+amqp+or+rabbitmq?sort=active&pagesize=50). The lack of this functionality is the only thing holding me back from switching away from SOStacked to the official Stack Exchange iOS app.

**Edit**: What's funny about this is that I **am** able to get the desired functionality in the official Stack Exchange iOS app by clicking on the link to my bookmark that I posted in this question while inside the app ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcOsN.jpg))! Now if there was a menu item for me to click on from inside the app that would just take me directly to that view then my day would be made.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229975/152859), such feature exists, you need to sort by "Favorite". I switched to android so can't check it myself, but this does look promising. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that only seems to sort the list of tags. What I want is a feed of questions (sorted by activity) which were tagged with any of my favorite tags.

Comment: Long shot... but what happens if you type this in the *Search* textbox of the app? `intags:mine`

Comment: @ShadowWizard it still shows individual rows for both answers and questions. I only want the questions.

Comment: And if you add `is:question` to it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard that does seem to accomplish what I need. Now I just need to be able to navigate to that page within, let's say, two clicks from opening the app.

Comment: Looks like you can [save your searches](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243537/152859) in the iOS app - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm looking for a way to do it with less than the current 4 clicks. I also want the view to be able to be refresh by pulling-to-refresh which this view currently doesn't have. To refresh this view I have to click the search box again, and click my most recent search again. The other problem with this method is that if I perform any other searches, this query will get lost in all my other recent searches. Why can't this view just be an option under on the "Tags" panel listed as "All"? What I want is a permeant way to get to this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be added in 1.4.4.4 with [new nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav).

Following your [bookmarked link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js+or+browserify+or+gulp+or+requirejs+or+slickgrid+or+soundmanager2+or+web-audio+or+underscore.js+or+lodash.js+or+backbone.js+or+html5-audio+or+xmlhttprequest+or+promise+or+cross-domain+or+soundcloud+or+amqp+or+rabbitmq?sort=active&pagesize=50) will bring you to a screen like this:

> [image: Screenshot of new nav after following the above link]

You can then customize, save, rename, and reorder it to be your first sort option.  It's currently more limited than the web in the number of ways you can filter the questions but the base functionality is there.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! Thank you so much for adding this feature.