# Search history in android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I would like to have "Search queries History" in the app, that will show me a list of my past searches.

Can this please be added?

Comment: Nice idea, worth to mention [this is possible in the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229483/show-recent-searches-in-ios-app).